# Lag using SKAction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, lag, skaction

I've finished my game which uses the method `+ (SKAction *)moveToY:(CGFloat)y duration:(NSTimeInterval)sec` to move sprites and when they collide with another sprite they disappear but when one of them collides with another object and disappears the other sprites that are falling down make some lag and I don't know if I could use another method to move sprites without lag.

PS: The sprites move a little bit fast(from `y:0`to `y:568` in 0.5 seconds), is that maybe the problem?

Comment: Post relevant sections of the code (ie contact event, removal). I suspect you are using physics and allowed the bodies to generate both contact (overlap) and collision (altering position/velocity) events. You would have to disallow collision if you don't want bodies to be momentarily stopped by a collision.

Comment: Your question is too broad and does not provide enough information for an answer.

Comment: @sangony I don't know how to explain it good but I have multiple objects moving on the screen and when one of them collides with a static object the rest objects that are moving stop for a very little period of time and that causes lag on the game.

Comment: Then as a starter, post all (but only) the pieces of code which deal with the collision and any subsequent actions (code) that happen as a result of the collision.